# which is the best way to save and display parent nodes with different child nodes(json)

Tags: mysql, sql, json

My script makes an ajax request to a json as you can se below:

```
{"boxes": [{
    "type": "cover",
    "name": "Name",
    "manu":"Manu",
    "img": "img.jpg",
},{
    "type": "type1",
    "store":"Store",
    "src": "Src",
    "link":"link",
    "de":"de",
    "por": "por"
},{
    "type": "article",
    "site":"site",
    "src": "src",
    "link":"link",
    "title": "title",
    "txt": "txt"
},{
    "type": "image",
    "src": "src",
    "link":"link"
},{
    "type": "video",
    "channel":"channel",
    "name": "name",
    "video":"video"
}]}
```

I would like to know which is the best way to save and display this data because if I save all content in a json file as it is now, the file gets huge and it is not good for performance.

I tried to save it in a BD (MySql) but as each parent node has diferent child nodes, I couldn't save it in the same table.

Someone has ideas to solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: which version of SQL are you going to use? tSQL etc.. and what is your SQL Engine SQL SERVER, ORACLE etc..? Also is the format of the JSON going to be always the same?

Comment: I edited my question. I was using MySql, but I don't think it's relevant. Regarding the json, it's going to have this structure. More nodes can be included but they will have one of others node's type.